# CompletableFuture get result of first future waiting for other futures depending of first one

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have following requirements.

1. CreateDocument
2. For document create many release notes (releaseNotesFuture)
3. For document create many parcels (parcelsFuture)
4. return objectId of document created in 1.

this is my current code:

```
public CompletableFuture<ObjectId> createDeliveryNoteDocument(String productId, List<String> releaseNotesIds) {
        CompletableFuture<ObjectId> deliveryNoteFuture =
                CompletableFuture
                        .supplyAsync(() -> sequenceServiceFeignClient.getNextValueForSequenceNameNoResponseEntity(DocumentType.DELIVERYNOTE.toString()))
                        .whenComplete((result, error) -> {
                            if (error != null)
                                logger.error("Unable to get next sequence number for DELIVERYNOTE sequence", error);
                        })
                        .thenCompose(seqNumber -> {
                            Set<ObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new HashSet<>();
                            objectAttributes.add(new ObjectAttribute(Constants.Document.DOCUMENT_TYPE, DocumentType.DELIVERYNOTE.toString()));
                            objectAttributes.add(new ObjectAttribute(Constants.Document.DOCUMENT_NO, seqNumber));
                            objectAttributes.add(new ObjectAttribute(Constants.Document.PRODUCT_ID, productId));
                            return objectCommandService.createCustomObject(new ObjectTypeTableName(Constants.ObjectTables.DOCUMENT), objectAttributes);
                        });
        CompletableFuture<Void> releaseNotesFuture =
                deliveryNoteFuture
                        .thenComposeAsync(deliveryNoteId -> joinReleaseNotesWithDeliveryNote(deliveryNoteId, releaseNotesIds));

        CompletableFuture<Void> parcelsFuture =
                deliveryNoteFuture
                        .thenComposeAsync(deliveryNoteId -> changeParcelsStatusForReleaseNotes(releaseNotesIds));

        return deliveryNoteFuture;
    }
```

how could I wait for `releaseNotesFuture` and `parcelsFuture`completion and then return `deliveryNoteFuture` result or error if any of `releaseNotesFuture` or `parcelsFuture` finished exceptionally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of returning `deliveryNoteFuture`, you'll have to have a `CompletableFuture` that is completed when the `releaseNotesFuture` and `parcelsFuture` are completed. Furthermore, you'll want that future to then compose into the result of `deliveryNoteFuture`, since you want its `ObjectId` if the whole chain is successful.

Something like

```
return CompletableFuture.allOf(releaseNotesFuture, parcelsFuture).thenComposeAsync(r -> deliveryNoteFuture);
```

Since both `releaseNotesFuture` and `parcelsFuture` are dependent on `deliveryNoteFuture`, errors from `deliveryNoteFuture` will propagate through all these chains.

Similarly, if either of `releaseNotesFuture` or `parcelsFuture` fail, the [`CompletableFuture` returned by `allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) will be completed with that failure's cause and that cause will be propagated to the future returned by `thenComposeAsync`. Otherwise, the result of `deliveryNoteFuture` will be delivered.

---

As [Holger suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704389/completablefuture-get-result-of-first-future-waiting-for-other-futures-depending/44704740#comment76393391_44704740), since you only have those two futures, you could also use [`thenCombine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCombine-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
releaseNotesFuture.thenCombineAsync(parcelsFuture, (x, y) -> deliveryNoteFuture.join());
```

Here, the `join()` won't block since `deliveryNoteFuture` is definitely already completed. Again, if the `deliveryNoteFuture` had originally failed, its cause will be propagated down the chain ending with the `CompletableFuture` returned by `thenCombineAsync`.

Comment: Or `releaseNotesFuture.thenCombine(parcelsFuture, (x, y) -> deliveryNoteFuture.join());`